# How to change the n consequence number of values in dataframe variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

This might seems very basic, but I am really stuck as newbie in `R` to figure it out how to change the `n` **consequence** number of values in `dataframe` `variable`  in `R`?

let'say in `mtcars` dataset I want to do the following operations:

1. change the first 20 rows of `mtcars$mpg` values to `NA`

I use the following `scripts` but of course they are not useful!

```
mtcars$mpg[, 1:20] <- NA
```

Any help with explanation is highly appreciated. 
Tnx

Comment: `mtcars$mpg[1:20] <- NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mtcars$mpg` is a vector and vectors only support indexing with a single argument, e.g. `x[i]`, whereas you're using an index with to arguments `x[i,j]`.

Data-frames on the other hand, being 2-dimensional structures, can be indexed with two arguments.

So, it's either

```
mtcars$mpg[1:20] <- NA
```

or

```
mtcars[1:20, 'mpg'] <- NA
```

Either of the two will work.